# Different behavior between the normal python list and the numpy array object

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Straight to the point. The next statements have the effect of swapping the contents of the two list elements of the python 2D-list:

```
a = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]]
b = [[7,8,9],
     [10,11,12]]

tmp = a[1]
a[1] = b[1]
b[1] = tmp
```

output:

```
a = [[1,2,3],
     [10,11,12]]

b = [[7,8,9],
     [4,5,6]]
```

For the numpy array type this would not have happened.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6]])
b = np.array([[7,8,9],
              [10,11,12]])

tmp = a[1]
a[1] = b[1]
b[1] = tmp
```

output:

```
a = array([[ 1,  2,  3],
           [10, 11, 12]])

b = array([[ 7,  8,  9],
           [10, 11, 12]])
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of lists are nested objects. The NumPy array is not nested but 2D. There is no notion of 2D with lists. So you have a list in a list. Whereas in NumPy it is just one object.

NumPy always returns a view when indexing and the result of indexing is another array. You need to make explicit copies:

```
tmp = a[1].copy()
a[1] = b[1].copy()
b[1] = tmp
```

to get it swapped:

```
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12]])
>>> b
array([[7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Rule of thumb:

1. Indexing of list in list == reference to sub-list
2. Indexing of NumPy 2D array along first dimension == view, i.e. shared data

Comment: Slicing a list produces a shallow copy, but indexing does something even shallower, sometimes referred to as a "reference copy" or "not a copy".

Comment: @user2357112 You are right. Improved my answer accordingly.

Comment: @user2357112 could you please elaborate on that a little more. As I understand this, a reference copy is some kind of a shallow copy (a shallow copy that can and will change the actual object if changed, i.e. not a lazy copy). So why do you make it sound like they are two different things? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Lockon2000: Slicing a list produces a new list object with references to the same elements the original list had references to. Indexing a list doesn't produce any new objects at all; it just gives you a reference to the object the corresponding list cell had a reference to.